# Three numbers after dash in transaction id

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

In Bitcoin Core the transaction id is appended with a dash and three numbers. They are usually 000. What do those numbers mean?

For example: b75b91ffc4b6f22b779ce45e4b140cf1d29dc894e368e3d8389c42444f870d5d-**000**

Answer (score 2):

It's the index of the output in the transaction that credits you.

It's a bit of an unused format; typically ':n' is used, rather than '-nnn'.

This is because an entry in the transaction ledger doesn't really corresponding to one transaction, but to one output of it. For example, a transaction could have multiple outputs that all credit you.

Comment: Oh, no! Bitcoin-Qt starting from version 0.9.0 uses this in transaction description dialog. For example: Status: 94 confirmations //
Date: 03.08.2014 03:01 //
Credit: 0.00012886 BTC //
Net amount: +0.00012886 BTC //
Transaction ID: 8c19f75d82f1d789b1f5762afc1ce9a36848af4aa9780c96ec02d99be9ca3edf-000 // This is transaction ID, nothing about its outputs

Comment: As I said, what the ledger calls "transactions" are really transaction outputs. The -nnn part identifies which output of that txid the entry is about.